# Getting the name and value of Jquery UI drag and drop boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having trouble getting the values from the boxes I am using as drag and drop boxes. the boxes drag and drop properly plus I am able to update a div with a value but I would like the value from the dragged box to be put in the div that I am appending along with the value of the box I am dragging the dragged box over. Here is the code so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is what I have so far and the link to the page im making the code on

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        // make orange boxes draggable
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
        //make blue boxes draggable but also make things mappen when orange box is dropped in it
        $( ".droppable" ).draggable().droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                var targetElem = $(this).attr("title");
                // update the div at the top of the page with the value of the blue box being dropped on and the orange box being dragged
                $('#showstuff').empty();
                $('#showstuff').append('' + targetElem + '');
            }
        });
        // when an orange box is dragged away from the blue box append the #showstuff div
        $( ".droppable" ).draggable().droppable({
            out: function(event, ui) {
                $('#showstuff').empty();
                $('#showstuff').append('emptied again');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the link is here

http://barrysfiles.co.uk/exp/development-bundle/demos/droppable/barrytest2.php

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your question correctly, but are you looking for a handle for the box you just dropped ? If so take a look at ui.draggable.

Comment: hi - I am using ui draggable already for the page I have posted in the link above. What I want to happen is when I drag the orange box over the blue box the name of the orange box is to be put in the div at the top of the screen along side the name of the blue box. As all boxes will have different names, it is not simply a case of drag and drop. Please look at the code and the page I have posted.

Comment: I put an example for jsfiddle to clearify my anwser. Or do you want to catch the date while the draggable elemt hover the dropbox without being relaesed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Dragged elment with ui.draggable from the drop callback.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TfmZt/

Comment: hi all. i got this working after a few hours - thanks for your help though.